# SSRS Data hidden on screen but visible when exported to PDF

Tags: reporting-services

I am facing a peculiar issue in a report using SSRS. When I run the report in BIDS the report runs fine. When I deploy to my report server - we are using sharepoint integrated mode - a particular section is hidden. When I export to PDF from the report server the section magically appears.

The section does have some visibility criteria set but its not on render formats - instead on fields.

BTW - this is the expression I am using:

=IIF(Fields!Item16Status.Value = "NA", True, False).

Also this is happening only for one particular value of input parameters.

I have included the screenshots from BIDS and server for reference here.

Any suggestions to resolve this would be great.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: I've had this issue.. what version of reporting services are you using? Did you "upgrade" this report from an older version? Open the report in VS or what every it is that you are using to write.. take out bits of your expression.. save it.. and put the expression back in.. re upload load the report.. and watch the magic happen! frustrating.. but this is exactly what I had to do!

Comment: I am using SSDT 2012. No I did not upgrade from any older version. The frustrating part is that its working in VS.

Comment: Yes, the same happened to me.. VS fine.. but the website showed it as blank.. but pdf output was fine.. give my suggestion a go.. remove bits of expressions that do not show save.. close and re add.. etc

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by deleting and recreating the tablix. May be the tablix was corrupted. I did play around with the HTML code which might have caused this. Even when I removed the hidden expression for all the rows it was still not being displayed - that led to the thought that the tablix might have been corrupted.